# PHP if statement testing and storing

Tags: php, if-statement

first of all sorry for title - i don't know how to put it better...
I need to test if something is an empty string and if it is not than I want to store it. I have something like this:

```
if (getStringBetween($array[0], "house", "dog") <> '') {
   $text = getStringBetween($array[0], "house", "dog");
}
```

Can it be make shorter so I don't repeat this *getStringBetween($array[0], "house", "dog")* twice.

I know I can do it this way:

```
$a = getStringBetween($array[0], "house", "dog");
if ($a <> '') {
   $text = $a;
}
```

but is this the best way? Can it be done without storing this "extra" $a variable?

Thanks!

Comment: The second way is about as close to the "best" way as you can get without moving into "improper", less readable code.

Comment: The second way is performanter then the first one (calling getStringBetween only once)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$text = (getStringBetween($array[0], "house", "dog") != ""?getStringBetween($array[0], "house", "dog"):NULL);
```

If the return value of `getStringBetween()` is unequal to an empty string it get's assigned, otherwise NULL get's assign, so the variable is not set. (BTW: I used `!=` instead of `<>`, because you don't see this too often in php, most likely in SQL)

Also I think this is at the border between saving code and making it unreadable. So it's your decision which one you want to use.

Comment: Though this answer would probably do, it does not (IMHO) reflect the exact semantic in the OP's code sample. What if there was an `if` condition further down the line like: `if(isset($text)){ //do something }`, then it will return `true` with your ternary code, though `false` in the OPs setup!

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo No when you check if isset and the variable has the value NULL it will fail

Comment: Woww! You're absolutely correct @Rizier123 as I just confirmed. What misconception I've been under for so long! I just tested that and was surprised: `$VAR = NULL;
var_dump($VAR);
var_dump(isset($VAR));`  gave something like: `NULL bool(false)`. Apologies and Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern is okay:

```
$a = getStringBetween($array[0], "house", "dog");
if ($a <> '') {
  $text = $a;
}
```

You are not really "storing the extra $a variable", are you?`

The first statement stores the variable in $a.

The `if` block uses the stored $a to evaluate your condition (`$a <> ''`).

The `$text = $a` uses the same stored value in $a for assignment to $text.

Seems all correct to me (and more optimal as the function `getStringBetween` is evaluated only once).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if ( strlen(($text = getStringBetween($array[0], "house", "dog"))) > 0) {
    echo $text;
}
else {
    echo "text is empty";
}
```